# Where is module './get-username'?

Tags: automation, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, recaptcha, google-chrome-headless

I am attempting to write a script using the puppeteer library for node and I'm running it on the microtask platform rapidworkers.com

I have run into a challenge when writing part of the script that solves the captcha on the rapidworkers login page, when I try to run my script with node index.js I get the error: Cannot find module './get-username'

here is my code: (copied from https://jsoverson.medium.com/bypassing-captchas-with-headless-chrome-93f294518337)

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    const request = require('request-promise-native');
    const poll = require('promise-poller').default;

    const siteDetails = {
    sitekey: '6LeEP20UAAAAAPYQsP7kIhE7XUT_LsDYjzO46uG3',
    pageurl: 'https://rapidworkers.com/Login'
  }

    const getUsername = require('./get-username');
    const getPassword = require('./get-password');
    const apiKey = require('./api-key');

    const chromeOptions = {
     executablePath:'/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google 
     Chrome',
     headless:false, 
     slowMo:10,
     defaultViewport: null
    };

    (async function main() {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch(chromeOptions);

      const page = await browser.newPage();

      await page.goto('https://rapidworkers.com/Login');

      const requestId = await initiateCaptchaRequest(apiKey);

      await page.type('#username', getUsername());

      const password = getPassword();
      await page.type('#password', password);

      const response = await pollForRequestResults(apiKey, requestId);

      await page.evaluate(`document.getElementById("g-recaptcha- 
   response").innerHTML="${response}";`);

      page.click('#register-form button[type=submit]');
    })()

    async function initiateCaptchaRequest(apiKey) {
      const formData = {
        method: 'userrecaptcha',
        googlekey: siteDetails.sitekey,
        key: apiKey,
        pageurl: siteDetails.pageurl,
        json: 1
      };
      const response = await request.post('http://2captcha.com/in.php', {form: 
    formData});
      return JSON.parse(response).request;
    }

    async function pollForRequestResults(key, id, retries = 30, interval = 1500, 
    delay = 15000) {
      await timeout(delay);
      return poll({
        taskFn: requestCaptchaResults(key, id),
        interval,
        retries
      });
    }

    function requestCaptchaResults(apiKey, requestId) {
      const url = `http://2captcha.com/res.php? 
   key=${apiKey}&action=get&id=${requestId}&json=1`;
      return async function() {
        return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject){
          const rawResponse = await request.get(url);
          const resp = JSON.parse(rawResponse);
          if (resp.status === 0) return reject(resp.request);
          resolve(resp.request);
        });
      }
    }

    const timeout = millis => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 
    millis))
```

Comment: Just replace those with your username / password

Comment: then it says module not found './myusername@outlook.com'

Comment: No, just take those functions out and do const username = ''myusername@outlook.com"